# Не работает фильтр по диапазону Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Мне нужно получать посты в котором есть добавленные meta, с помощью плагина ACF.

```
function pro_filter($query){
        if(is_admin()) return;
        if(!$query->is_main_query()) return;

        $meta = array('relation' => 'AND',
                      array(
                         'key'     => 'home_square_feet'
                         'value'   => array(5, 99),
                         'type'    => 'NUMERICAL',
                         'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
         ));

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta);
    }
```

Но посты я не получаю. Но если я изменю `'value'   => array(0, 99),` на 0, 99 то он находит. В посте число 5.

Comment: Не знаю, поможет ли, но `'type'` должен быть `'NUMERIC'`,  а не `'NUMERICAL'`. В документации нет такого значения как `'NUMERICAL'`.

Comment: Да, это помогло. Странно что в просторах интернета мне выдавало что `'type'=>'NUMERICAL'`, хотя это не правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'type'` должен быть `'NUMERIC'`, а не `'NUMERICAL'`

Спасибо [Simon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211900/simon)